# SQL Azure Data Sync migration of Stored Procedures?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, sqldatasource

I have successfully implemented a POC that uses the SQL Azure Data Sync tool. However, it is quite literally "Data" because none of my stored procedures were implemented.

1. Is it possible to use the same tool to automatically sync my stored procedures? I have found the "Update Schema" button in Azure but that seems to only refer to table schema and nothing else.
2. If the above is not possible, what is the most effective way for me to migrate all of my stored procedures from Azure to my local client? My local is SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Answer (score 1):

SQL Azure Data Sync does exactly what it's name states--it synchronizes your data which is in your Tables. Stored Procedures are not included because they contain no data. The SQL Server Mangagement Studio Generate Scripts Wizard is an easy means of producing a script that will copy all of your Stored Procedures to another database.